# Blocking by functions bound to Backbone triggered events

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-events

If I have a function bound to a Backbone object event, will triggering that event from another context block programme flow until the bound functions have executed?

For example, a collection of todos:

```
class App.Collections.Todos extends Backbone.Collection
  model: App.Models.Todo

  initialize: ->
    @collection.on 'will_change:selected', @logUnselection, this
    @collection.on 'change:selected', @logSelection, this

  logUnselection: (todo) ->
    for t in @collection.models
      console.log "unselected!"

  logSelection: (todo) ->
    console.log "selected!"
```

And the view for a single todo has this:

```
class App.Views.Todo extends Backbone.View

  events:
    'click': 'select'

  select: (e) ->
    @model.collection.trigger('will_change:selected', @model)
    @model.set(selected: true)
```

When clicking a todo will the output always look like this, no matter how long the code in `logUnselection` takes to execute?

```
unselected!
unselected!
unselected!
unselected!
...
unselected!
selected!
```

Or will execution continue while the event triggers the bound function, possibly resulting in this:

```
unselected!
unselected!
selected!
unselected!
...
unselected!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger will block execution.

From [Backbone's annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html), this is what is happening when you call trigger. You can see that the triggerEvents function simply executes the registered events for this trigger.

```
trigger: function(name) {
  if (!this._events) return this;
  var args = slice.call(arguments, 1);
  if (!eventsApi(this, 'trigger', name, args)) return this;
  var events = this._events[name];
  var allEvents = this._events.all;
  if (events) triggerEvents(events, args);
  if (allEvents) triggerEvents(allEvents, arguments);
  return this;
},

... 

var triggerEvents = function(events, args) {
var ev, i = -1, l = events.length, a1 = args[0], a2 = args[1], a3 = args[2];
switch (args.length) {
  case 0: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx); return;
  case 1: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, a1); return;
  case 2: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, a1, a2); return;
  case 3: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, a1, a2, a3); return;
  default: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.apply(ev.ctx, args); return;
}
};
```